# Parsing the name of MySQL tables into Json to then be loaded into a dropdown box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I want to take the names of my tables from my SQL database and put them in a dropdown box which will then be used to display the data from the selected table on the index.html page.

At the moment, the dropdown box is populated with pure JSON data rather than anything that looks normal.

Here are my code files:

db.php

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "db_12058661";
?>
```

mysql.php

```
<?php 

require("db.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id == 1){
$query=new     PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$hostname","$username","$password");
$statement=$query->prepare("SELECT * FROM $id");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
}
?>
```

tables.php

```
<?php 
require_once("db.php");

$query=new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$hostname","$username","$password");
$statement=$query->prepare("show tables");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);

echo ($json);

?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand">Michael Delahorne 12058661</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <select name="options" id="options" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">People</option>
                    <option value="2">Animals</option>
                    <option value="3">Shapes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="table">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("option").load('tables.php');
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#options").change(function() {
    $("#table").load('mysql.php?id=' + $(this).val());
}); })
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("tables.php", function (data){
        var jsonData
        $.each(data, function(i, menuItems){
            jsonData = '<select>' + jsonData + '</select>';
            $(jsonData).appendTo('#options');
            alert(1);
        }) 
    })
})



</script>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: plus your .each() loop doesn't actually **USE** the json you get back. you just continually build up a nested `<select><select>....</select></select>`, and then stuffs that into ANOTHER `<select>` in the html.

Comment: Really? What do I need to change to fix that? I've taken the pre configured <select>s out of the HTML but that didn't change anything.

Comment: `jsondata = '<option>' + menuItems + '</option>'` maybe?

Comment: The dropdown box now has 3 entries, all saying [object Object]. Getting somewhere though!

Comment: Call it in a stored procedure, do not build a inline string SQL Query like that. Then test that only the wanted param are expected to fix the slq injection aspect.